# How to get content of body tag and store it in a variable by using getElementsByTagName() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get value from body tag. First i have created ajax request in that when request get processed and returns the response to same page in that i i have taken a variable temp. in that variable whole html code is getting store with the output(now here output is content of body tag). like e.g in body tag some numbers are there. Now i want only the body content is get stored in the another variable by using getElementsByTagName method. i have tried with this but it shows getElementsByTagName is not a function. Please show me how to store the contents of body tag  in a variable. This is related question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918875/how-print-record-from-database-when-user-select-options-from-dropdown-menu-dyna/55921444#55921444) question. Please do check for more details.

```
request.onreadystatechange= function() 
{
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) 
    {
           var temp = this.responseText;
           var tepo = temp.getElementsByTagName("body");
           console.log(tepo);

    }
};
```

This is result of this.responseText

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       -0.2
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `temp.getElementsByTagName("body")` This wont work unless temp points to `document` object. Moreover what is the response that you are getting?

Comment: so how do i take body content from this.reponseText. because in this.responceText contain body tag in that the output what i'm expecting is present .!!!!!!!!

Comment: Unless and until you post your `responseText` we cannot assume the structure and provide you with a solution. So please post the minimal response required

Comment: i assume the data being sent back is in JSON format? If so you could do `temp.body` but you will need to check with the response data

Comment: var temp = document.this.responseText;
console.log(temp);
this is also not working.!!!!!

Comment: can you edit your post to include `this.responseText`?

Comment: i have added what this.responceText contain. so here i want -0.2 value is get store in one separate variable of javascript

Comment: Can you tell what is the result of `typeof this.responseText` ?

Comment: please read the description carefully i have already added.

Comment: please read my comment and respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsp page ,do like below :

```
 //this will return as response to ajax
    <% out.println("-0.2");  %>
```

And you will need to get that value :

```
  var temp = this.responseText;//here temp will have -0.2
   console.log(temp);
  alert(temp);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193025/discussion-on-answer-by-swati-how-to-get-content-of-body-tag-and-store-it-in-a-v).