# How to create dynamic options for select box using array elements ? and use that option box value in another jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, select, arraylist

This Question is Linked with [this][1] question. I'm trying to create dynamically generated options for the select box using array elements. meanwhile, I want all the array elements to get displayed as an option in the select box. and also I want to use that all elements in another JSP page. I really don't have an idea of how to make this possible.

In program "var jsArray[]" which is JavaScript array, this array contains all the values which I want to display those values as an option in the select box. I have tried some code but it's not working properly. For the simplicity only required code I'll be posting here.

```
var difference_ms = 3;

var jsArray =[]; 
                <%
                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
                    %>
               // putting value in  jsArray  i.e at  jsArray[0]=first element ..so on 
                jsArray[<%= i %>] = "<%= ar.get(i) %>"; 

              <% } %>
                var select  ="";
             for (var i = 0; i < difference_ms; i++) 
             {
             $('<div class="align" id="' + i + '">'+select+'<input class="space2 
             size"type="text" id="amit' + i + '"><span><select><option value="FULL DAY">
             FULL DAY</option><option value="HALF DAY">HALF DAY</option></select></div>
             <br><br>').appendTo('#container');
            }

<div id="container"></div>



---------Process.jsp----------------------------------------

<%
           String s = request.getParameter("val");
           String user_mail = request.getParameter("user_mail");

           ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
           String array_value_ar = "";
           String temp = "";

           if(s==null || s.trim().equals(""))
            {  
                // out.print("Please enter id");  
            }
            else
            {  
            //int id=Integer.parseInt(emp);  
                // out.println(id);
            try
            {  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registerdb", "root", "");  
            PreparedStatement ps_leave = con.prepareStatement("select leave_Name from orgleave");
            ResultSet rs_leave = ps_leave.executeQuery();
            while(rs_leave.next())
            {
                array_value_ar = rs_leave.getString("leave_name");
                ar.add(array_value_ar);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++)
            {
                temp = (ar.get(i)).toString();
            if(s.equals(temp))
            { 
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select balance_leave from user_assign_leave where user_email=?"); 
                ps.setString(1,user_mail);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) 
                { 
                    out.print(rs.getString("balance_leave"));
                }
            }
            }
          /*  else if(s.equals("TYPE B"))
            { 
                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("select rem_type_b from request where emp_id=?"); 
                ps1.setString(1,user_mail); 
                ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
                if(rs1.next()) 
                { 
                    out.print(rs1.getDouble("rem_type_b")); 
                }
            } 
            else if(s.equals("TYPE C"))
            { 
                PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement("select rem_type_c from request where emp_id=?"); 
                ps2.setString(1,user_mail); 
                ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                if(rs2.next()) 
                { 
                    out.print(rs2.getDouble("rem_type_c")); 
                }
            }  */ 
                con.close(); 
            } 
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} 
            }   
       %>

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918875/how-print-record-from-database-when-user-select-options-from-dropdown-menu-dyna/55921444#55921444
```

Comment: i can post whole code if anyone want or interested to go through it.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use `for-loop` inside your `append` , try to store your `select` string in some `variable` and `append` it there like for example try below code ,also i have not tested this code it might be having some syntax error :

```
     var difference_ms = 3;
                //declare empty array
                var jsArray =[]; 
                <%
                for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
                    % >
               // putting value in  jsArray  i.e at  jsArray[0]=first element ..so on 
                jsArray[<%= i %>] = "<%= columns.get(i) %>"; 

              <% } %>
               var select  ="";
          //looping through value and adding it in select box in var select as you cannot used for loop inside your append so storing value here  
              for(var j = 0; j < jsArray.length; j++) {
              select += '<select class="space" onchange ="sendInfo(this.value,' + i + ');"><option>SELECT</option><option value="'+ jsArray[j]+'">"'+jsArray[j]+'"</option></select>';

              }
   // putting select value in your append 
            for (var i = 0; i < difference_ms; i++) {
             $('<div class="align" id="' + i + '">'+select+'
             <input class="space2 size"type="text" id="amit' + i + '">
           <span><select><option value="FULL DAY">FULL DAY</option>
           <option value="HALF DAY">HALF DAY</option></select></div><br> 
             <br>').appendTo('#container');
            }
 <div id="container"></div>
```

---

Edit:
Try like below:

```
select='<select class="space" onchange ="sendInfo(this.value,' + i + ');"><option>SELECT</option>';
for(var j = 0; j < jsArray.length; j++) {
       //appending new option in selectbox
              select += '<option value="'+ jsArray[j]+'">"'+jsArray[j]+'"</option>';

              }
           select+= '</select>';
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193857/discussion-on-answer-by-swati-how-to-create-dynamic-options-for-select-box-using).

Comment: @Swati First -> click on the button which located at right corner of the screen [stack exchange button]. then second in that section of current community you can see their button of chat click on that. then next look at the right corner bottom their you'll see "hide frozen rooms" button. so left side of the button "create room" button click on that button and this way you can create a room. i can't see this button because of less than 50 reputation of my profile. but you'll see that button. :)

Comment: @Swati you cannot move comments to a room when any participant has less than 20 reputation

Comment: @Swati can you join the room again! I have updated my code as per our discussion.